# How does the WP7 CompassReading determine the TrueHeading from the MagneticHeading?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, magnetometer

I've installed the code from [How to: Get Data from the Compass Sensor for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202974%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) onto my dev unlocked HTC Trophy 7 phone running Mango.

The magnetic north heading that is returned seems to be correct. I've compared it to a traditional compass and an iPhone compass application and the heading is more or less the same give or take a degree.

The value returned from CompassReading.[TrueHeading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.sensors.compassreading.trueheading%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) however seems to be significantly off.

For my location I looked up the [magnetic declination](http://magnetic-declination.com/) as being:

> Latitude: 41° 22' 36.5" S
>   Longitude: 173° 16' 34.9" E
>   Magnetic declination: 22° 2' EAST 
>   Declination is POSITIVE
>   Inclination: -66° 49'
>   Magnetic field strength: 56492.9 nT

Where as the phone is showing a magnetic declination of around 130° East.

I don't believe it is my implementation of the demo code causing the issue as I get the same incorrect values for a number of other apps from the marketplace.

**How is the value of TrueHeading being set by the phone/framework?**

Do I need to do something with the locaiton services so the correct value can be determined?

I've tried [asking HTC for support](http://www.fishofprey.com/2012/02/htc-trophy-7-compass-magnetic.html) but they indicated it was probably an OS issue.

I've also asked a similar question on [Microsoft Answers - HTC Trophy 7 can't determine true north correctly when using the compass](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-wpdevices/htc-trophy-7-cant-determine-true-north-correctly/498867d4-557e-4514-9946-bf927544376a)

Answer (score 2):

We spent a long time looking into different readings and what they mean. I'd suggest comparing the results you get form your app against one of the other apps on the marketplace that give you a north direction. e.g. HeadsUpCompass (ours), Compass VO, Compass 7 were the ones I checked aganst.

My experience was the CompassReading was way off when the phone was not flat. So we used the Motion API to work out the phones heading when the phone is upright and the Compass API when the phone is flat. I've checked the code of HUC and we are using compassSensor.CurrentValue.TrueHeading has the heading. This was tested on HTC HD7, Mazza and Trophy (what we had at the time).

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking at HeadsUpCompass running on my phone right now. I've allowed location use and set it to Geographic North. The reported Declination of 22.1° seems right but the directions are all out. I'm beginning to suspect there is something wrong with my phone or the internal DLLs that ultimately populate the CompassReading struct.

Comment: If you think it is your phone that is at fault, it is worth taking a bit of time to try and calibrate the sensors properly. We tried to write instuctions in the help page, but I think they are lost in the explaination of declination. Try the waving in a figure of eight as described on MSDN. Or point the phone in each direction on (north, south, east, west, up, down) for about 10 seconds each.

Comment: I went through the steps you described for both the figure eight and the robust steps and the only thing I achieved was amusing my coworkers :) . Both before and after calibration the accuracy was at 5°. On Monday I'm meeting with our local Microsoft Rep so I'll do some comparisons with other phones.

Answer (score 2):

I bet you live in the Southern hemisphere.

As far as I know, Mango has a software issue of returning correct declination,
which happens **only in the southern hemisphere**.

Its been a while, but there is no patch or bug fix for this unfortunately...

Since it works in the North hemisphere, people living in Northern hemisphere claim it works fine on many forums.

Comment: I'm in New Zealand. I went down the rabbit hole of trying to report this bug to Microsoft/Nokia/HTC. The only conclusion I came up with is that either a) no one at Microsoft cares about the issue or b) no one at Microsoft will acknowledge the issue. I was holding out hope for WP8, but I've heard reports of the same issue. I'll try it from my Windows 8 tablet if I get a chance.

Comment: I've just noticed something possibly critical and come up with an idea and I think this works, if there is a way to pass magnetic declination value manually to the system...does anyone know how to??

Comment: what the heck!? I've found out one unbelievable fact on Lumia 800!!when the charger thing on top of the phone is opened, true north goes up to 350, when closed, correctly up to 360... has anyone noticed this?

Comment: The software in the phone needs to calculate the soft and hard iron offsets to correctly determine the magnetic field strength. It might be the opening the cover invalidates the current model, especially if a cable is attached.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a start in tracking down what is happening by loading Microsoft.Devices.Sensors.dll into ILSpy from:

> %Program Files%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71\Microsoft.Devices.Sensors.dll

There is an internal constructor on CompassReading that gets the TrueHeading value from an instance of CompassNativeSample.

```
internal CompassReading(CompassNativeSample nativeSample)
{
    this = default(CompassReading);
    this.Timestamp = nativeSample.header.TimeStamp;
    this.HeadingAccuracy = (double)nativeSample.wErrorMargin;
    this.TrueHeading = (double)nativeSample.wBearing;
    this.MagnetometerReading = new Vector3(nativeSample.vecMagCalibrated.X, nativeSample.vecMagCalibrated.Y, nativeSample.vecMagCalibrated.Z);
    this.MagneticHeading = (uint)nativeSample.wBearing - nativeSample.dwDeclAngle;
}
```

The MagneticHeading is then determined from the TrueHeading (wBearing) and the dwDeclAngle? This is confusing me a bit as the MagneticHeading is the one that seems correct.

As best I can tell the CompassNativeSample is coming up through through COM interop out of SensorsNative.ddl. It's all a bit of a blackbox below there.